# In PHP, how can you do multiple read/writes to a file with repeatedly closing it

Tags: php, fread

I'm creating a class that will store data in a file and I need to know if it's possible to do multiple read/writes using one file handle?

I've done some experiments, and using this code:

```
$file_name = 'test.txt';
$file = fopen($file_name, 'r+');
echo fread($file, filesize($file_name)) . "<hr />";
fwrite($file, "|".rand());
echo fread($file, filesize($file_name));
fclose($file);
```

The file gets read the first time, the write works, but the second fread is blank.

Using this code:

```
$file_name = 'test.txt';
$file = fopen($file_name, 'r+');
echo fread($file, filesize($file_name)) . "<hr />";
fwrite($file, "|".rand());
fclose($file);
$file = fopen($file_name, 'r+');
echo fread($file, filesize($file_name));
fclose($file);
```

The second fread then works, but it doesn't contain the data that was appended to it in the fwrite just above it.

So basically, I want to create a single file handle as a property of the class, and have it's methods refer to it when reading and writing, but including any changes that other methods might've made to the data.

I do have 2 alternatives if this isn't possible, one being opening and closing the file handle in each method but this seems really inefficient and I'm not sure what a single file open/close 'costs' in terms of performance. The other alternative is that the data is being converted into array for easy manipulation, I could update the array rather than the file every time but then when would I update the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`fseek`](http://php.net/fseek) to move your pointer within the file and read from there, *fread* and *fwrite* are moving that pointer forward.

And you have to use `a+` instead of `r+`, see: the mode of [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen)

Comment: Ok, cool - now the second read works but it doesn't include the data that was written to the file inbetween class to fread

Comment: You have to clear the cache `clearstatcache()` in-between otherwise the call to  `filesize` will be the same.